# Profile Page PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, user-profile

The profile page is using a PHP and MySQL to display the item.

 There are two things I want to ask tho 
Promise: If you can help me, I'll can acknowledge you in my website and put you in the credits ;)

 
**Question 1:** 
How to check if user exists in the database, and how to display a 404 message?

**Question 2:**  
So, the main bug here is when you search for the user, it doesn't recognize the user.
 User "admin01" search for himself and the profile page is working, if the user  *admin01*  search for the user  *admin02* , the page is not gonna give the users information. Anyway how to fix this?

 Additional Info:
The site is gonna use the GET method to check the url, example: `profile.php?username=admin01`, it's gonna display the user information. If the user isn't logged in, the page is gonna redirect to the login page.

Codes:

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com">Prospekt | A Gaming Community</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="../home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/forums.php">Forums</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Member - <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

 <div id="wrapper">

 <div class="container">

     <div class="page-header">
     <h1>Prospekt | A Gaming Community</h1>
     <h4> Dashboard |  See your live ranking, stats, and more! </h4>
     </div>
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
if (isset($username) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false){
  echo $username;
} else {
  echo "Please search for a valid user!";
}
 ?>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="assets/jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A side note: you are using a long deprecated database adapter (the old `mysql_...()` functions) and your script is _wide_ open to sql injection attacks... Please port your script to either `mysqli` or `PDO` as database adapters. Check the official documentation for that. And learn about the advantages of using "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to secure your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is actually only localhosted, as soon as I port it "online", this will gonna change, and I'll use mysqli or PDO later then :)

Comment: The answer to question 2 obviously is: at the beginning of the script you check if a session variable exists named like the user name specified as an argument. It is _very_ unlikely that this is the case for other users than the one currently logged in. So you actually prevent yourself what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: About porting: that is a totally unrealistic approach. The only way is to code proper inside your development environment and publish the code only when it is working as desired. It is unrealistic to "port it to PDO" as soon as you "port it online". Do it NOW.

Comment: changing from mysql to pdo later means you are doing the work twice. Get it right the first time.

Comment: Question 1 is obsolete: you already do that with your query, only you block it because of the reason given above as answer to question 2.

Comment: How do I supposed to delete if a session variable exists? Please put it on the answer list :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of that last question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips guys (and girls), any tutorial about making a social website with a Profile Page in it? I'm just a 13 y/o coder and i'm kinda new to PHP and MySQL (but i'm working on it) :)

Comment: Sorry didn't realilze you were just a kid :) please see my updated answer, I think it has what you want.

Comment: Well it's ok :) Age is just a number when it comes to coding :) Thanks for being friendly tho, I hope all of the programmers are friendly as you :)

Comment: Well, do you have any website that can teach me how to code a social website? (mainly using PDO and MySQL) Thanks and have a good day ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies mainly in the HTML that you have chosen to use. It gives the impression of being the one for a user's home page. You need to replace that HTML with a fresh one. And you need bit of PHP code like this

```
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 else {
   /* find out if a user exists and raise 404 if not? Here's how */

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['username'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        /* now an authenticated users is trying to see a profile page
           on your website for a user who exists */
        // CREATE THE APPROPRIATE HTML

    }
    else 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 not found');
    }
}
```

Note that I have use PDO. mysql_* functions should not be used. you are not escaping your query params in your current code. Deadly dangerous.

Note that the following lines in your original code should be removed:

```
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Comment: Actually you don't need such an explicit "check if user exists" query, the query the OP uses to _fetch_ the specified users data is sufficient for that. Though obviously it has to be modified to parameter binding.

Comment: My Question No.2 is: so, I searched for my own profile, and it is working, but when I searched for other profile, the profile.php just shows my own information, and btw, can you fix your code into an "fixed php code"?

Comment: This is 'fixed' code. Being PDO prepared statments it's not vulnerable to sql injections

Answer (score 0):

For Your Question No 2 : Add following condition where you are checking $_GET method

```
<?php
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    if (isset($username) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false && $username != $userRow['userName'] ){
       echo $username;
    } else {
       echo "Please search for a valid user!";
    }
 ?>
```

And for your Question No. 1 : You can check id you are not any array in SELECT Query You can change Header Location to 404 Page.